# Unable to read feed from https in MAMP

Tags: php, curl, https

I currently have PHP 5.6.10 installed on my Mac. I tried to pull data using following code from website with https enabled:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$url = "https://deshsanchar.com/feed";
file_put_contents("temp.xml", fopen($url, 'r'));
?>
```

However, the page shows following warning with empty temp.xml file:

> Warning: failed loading cafile stream: `⁨/⁨Applications/MAMP⁩/⁨htdocs⁩/cacert-2019-01-23.pem' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news/index.php on line 6
>
> Warning: fopen(): Failed to enable crypto in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news/index.php on line 6
>
> Warning: fopen(https://deshsanchar.com/feed): failed to open stream: operation failed in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/news/index.php on line 6

I had downloaded cacert-2019-01-23.pem file from https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html and kept it under ⁨Applications/MAMP⁩/⁨htdocs⁩/ directory and added some codes in php.ini:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
allow_url_include = On
curl.cainfo=⁨/⁨Applications/MAMP⁩/⁨htdocs⁩/cacert-2019-01-23.pem
openssl.cafile=⁨/⁨Applications/MAMP⁩/⁨htdocs⁩/cacert-2019-01-23.pem
```

I restarted MAMP server but its not working as expected.